# Why is the adjugate matrix the null matrix?

Tags: matrix-rank

I struggle to understand why if $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C}) $, $\det A=0$ and $rank A \le n-2$, then $A^*=O_n$. Could you please tell me why this claim holds? My textbook offers no proof for this.

Comment: Have you seen the result that $A$ has rank at most $n-2$ if and only if all $n-1$ minors are non-zero?  That is, have you seen anything about "determinantal rank"?

Comment: The result is explained/proved nicely [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187497/81360)

Comment: @Omnomnomnom You also explained it nicely [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921161/a-problem-on-rank-of-a-and-operatornameadja) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has rank${}<n-1$ then all $(n-1)\times(n-1)$ minors are equal to zero, and so ${\mathrm adj}(A)$ has rank$~0$.

Comment: Could you give me some further explainations? How come $adj(A)$ has rank 0?

Comment: See the answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921161/a-problem-on-rank-of-a-and-operatornameadja).