# The submatrix of a matrix in relation to the rank of the matrix

Tags: matrices

*Prove that if A has rank r > 0, then A has an r x r invertible matrix.*

I have tried looking at the properties of invertible matrices, but I can't prove those qualities using just the rank of matrix A.

Comment: Your question does not make sense as stated. Do you mean to show that $A$ has an $r \times r$ invertible *submatrix*?

Comment: Ben Grossmann, yes. I need to show that A has an r x r invertibe submatrix

Comment: Does [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/187497/81360) answer you question to your satisfaction?

Comment: It does. Thankyou!